# Creating a loss function with two minima?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I'm using keras to build a model. The model has one output, and I want a loss similar to mse loss, but there are two values to predict, and I'm fine if the model predicts either one of them, so I want the loss function to look something like this
[image: loss function]

(p.s. the graph doesn't have to be symmetrical)

Does any function like this exist? If not, how do I make one

Comment: Check this post for building a custom loss function in Keras: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818584/custom-loss-function-in-keras

Comment: my question is not how to build a loss function, I already know that. I'm just asking how to build a loss function suitable for this purpose, i.e. with two minimas

Comment: Wait, I am confused. Are you trying to predict two values at each run - corresponding to the minimum values of the graph, or predict just one value, and be OK if it is either of them? Meaning it is not a single valued function. If that is the case, I do not understand what that graph represents. Loss is a measure of error and if the function is multi valued, it is not well defined.

Comment: @serali The model has just one output. So, it has to predict one value that can be either of the two minimas, and I'm okay with either.

Answer (score 2):

You basically **don't want** to have a loss like that in any case.

The objective of Machine Learning is define a loss function that is **convex** to find the minimum by approximating it with the given data.

Not having a convex loss function means that you will have **multiple minima** and won't be able to determine if the one you're in is a global minimum or just a local one so you won't know if it's optimal or not.

The only kind of Machine Learning without convex function is **Deep Learning**. And you see how complicated it is to work with it and having "good results" without understanding what is happening under the hood.

Deep Learning models are (most of the time) stochastically with batch gradient descent, that helps getting out of local minima, but that's not even easy.

We can't even prove mathematically that these systems are well-optimized.

So basically, if you want a good model, you can avoid creating such a monster loss :)